# Insert newline character after every line using Python

Tags: python, formatting

I'm trying to insert a newline character into a text file after every line.

So if this is my data:

```
Dose    atRA_minus_tet  tet
0.001   5.100033162 0
0.001967886 9.651369961 0
0.003926449 16.72520921 0
```

I want:

```
Dose    atRA_minus_tet  tet

0.001   5.100033162 0

0.001967886 9.651369961 0

0.003926449 16.72520921 0
```

My code:

```
def prepare_steady_state_data(self,data_file):
    with open(data_file) as f:
        lines= [line+'\n' for line in f.readlines()]

    with open(data_file[:-4]+'_for_SS_Fit.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(str(lines))
```

The problem is that this writes the string literally, like so:

```
['Dose,Cyp26(atRA_plus_tet),Tet\n\n', '0.001,26.67599946,1\n\n', '0.001006932,26.89620879,1\n\n', '0.001013911,27.117882,1\n\n', '0.001020939,27.34102614,1\n\n']
```

How do I change this code so that I get the desired format in the output text file?

With thanks,

Ciaran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(data_file) as source:
    with open(data_file[:-4]+'_for_SS_Fit.txt','w') as output:
        for line in source:
            f.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: @user3059024 yw, don't forget to mark any question you deem solve the problem as "Accepted answer" :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
f.write(str(lines))
```

With

```
f.write(''.join(lines))
```